# A custom image style is not working

Tags: 7, views, media

I have created a block view with title and image using fields. When I use the default image styles, they work as they should.
The custom image style I created is a thumbnail (120 x 70) with canvas. When I try using this style in Views, I get the original image size.

Comment: How to you use the style in Views?

Comment: Did you change in your views, in image field settings change the display format in to image cache preset? or you just change the display form at in content type display settings only?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the image preset is created fine after applying the resize/crop function on
admin>config>media>image-styles

[image]

Just check the thumbnail(right one) is created fine by clicking on it.

Now when we add any image field in any view, make sure to use this style for display of this field

[image]

Please check with these points. 
And it works with Global text fields also.

Comment: @Constarr : It works with Global custom text fields also

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in a Global Text Area field and using the token to display it, it will not use the image style